# Infantilization as explanation for wide-spread fear in society?

Tags: reference-request, society

I came across the following quote in a radio programme ([*Das Philosophische Radio*](http://www.wdr5.de/sendungen/philosophischesradio/), in German) that is devoted to matters philosophy. The resulting question borders on sociology but I hope it is still okay to ask it here also due to its origin. A listener gave this possible explanation for wide-spread [fear in contemporary society](http://www.wdr5.de/sendungen/philosophischesradio/heinzbude108.html) (translation courtesy of Google Translate):

> To my mind, an increasing infantilization of society plays a role.
>   [Uncertainity is ill received]. [Taking] care of [yourself first] and [only] when it
>   is no longer [possible relying on the] help of others, no longer seems to be
>   the goal for many. The community, the state, it must [put everything right]. For
>   everything there must be someone to blame. The dangerous moments in
>   life are often acted out on a kind of game level such as bungee
>   jumping, free diving, free climbing. [But] in real life, nothing [bad must occur].

This sounds like an internally consistent argument that a (conservative) politician, sociologist, or philosopher might make. Is there any philosopher who comes to mind and whose work could serve as a basis for the listener's observation regarding a possible causal link between such infantilization (including virtual bravery) and fear (concrete anxiety)?

Comment: I would be careful with the term "conservative" here, as this resembles many who call themselves "classical liberals."

Comment: @JamesKingsbery Fair enough. The question does (should) not depend on this qualification.